# Divide the data into multiple sets using ShuffleSplit then storing each in a set

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have loaded the CIFAR10 dataset but I want to divide it into multiple splits.
Here is how I downloaded the dataset

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
```

Then I used ShuffleSplit to create a generator to split the data like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
rs = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=3, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)
splits = rs.split(x_train)
```

I know I can iterate over the generated splits using:

```
for train_index, test_index in splits:
  #train_index is a np array which hold the indies 
  print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
```

Assuming I want to have at the end.

> x_train1, y_train1, x_train2, y_train2, x_train3, y_train3

How can I divide the data based on the generated indices such that one training split which contain both the training and the testing indices?

I tried combining the indices into list or contacte the arrays but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do it :)

```
num_shreds = 10
shred_size = len(X_train)//num_shreds

X_train, y_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train)
shred_X = [X_train[i:i + shred_size] for i in range(0, shred_size* num_shreds, shred_size)]
shred_y = [y_train[i:i + shred_size] for i in range(0, shred_size* num_shreds, shred_size)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by using a different approach the code is below:

```
  partitions_train_x = []
  partitions_train_y = []
  partitions_test_x = []
  partitions_test_y = []
  x = np.arange(len(y_train))
  np.random.shuffle(x)
  indices = np.split(x, num_partitions)
    for data_indices in zip(indices):
      x = x_train[data_indices]
      y = y_train[data_indices]
      partions_train_x.append(x)
      partitions_train_y.append(y)

      x = np.arange(len(y_test))
      indices = np.split(x, num_partitions)
      for data_indices in zip(indices):
        x = x_test[data_indices]
        y = y_test[data_indices]
      partitions_test_x.append(x)
      partitions_test_y.append(y)
```

I know this may not be the best way to do, but it works.